# Adding custom callerid discord bot using twilio

Tags: node.js, discord, twilio, bots

how can i add custom callerid to my discord bot.

I want like !call "myphonenumber" "callerid" "yourservice"

myphonenumber -> my number
callerid -> who call my number

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The bot works fine but i do not know how to code that the bot can use custom valide callerid

Comment: I mean spoof callerid

Comment: Can you share the code you are using, so that we can work with it? It’s hard to point you in the right direction without knowing where you are starting from.

Comment: What code should i share ? call.js and config.js ?

Comment: Share the code that is relevant to your bot making calls. And tell us what you have tried with that code to achieve your outcome.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/YiPU8hhw - call.js

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WJ3Aza0r - config.js and i want to have custom callerid like !call <myphonenumber> <callerid> <welcome>

Comment: What does call.js do right now? It looks like it receives a webhook with details about a call that has already happened.

Comment: Yes it call the phone number, but what i want is not to call with just one callerid i want with custom valide phone number

Comment: I can’t see where it makes the call.

Comment: Oh i copied the wrong js call.js is get.js this is the call.js https://pastebin.com/KZSgEMgm

Comment: Ok, so you currently make the call using `config.callerId` as the `from` number. So to call from a different number you should pass in another number like you pass in the `to` number. But, you can only make calls from either a Twilio number or a number that you have verified in your Twilio account. You can’t just make calls from any number.